# The spam question keeps getting downvotes after removal

Tags: discussion, voting, spam, automatic-deletion

Today I was going through the review queues and found out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60201434) question which was definitely spam. So I flagged it as spam and also downvoted.

The Question score was -4 at that time and with my downvote, it reached to -5. Spam flag handling is faster than any other close vote flag so mine got addressed within minutes and was marked helpful.

By marking it as helpful it's supposed to get deleted. Now my question is if it gets deleted the moment spam flag is marked helpful how can it receive more downvotes. The moment when I checked if it was helpful or not at that time it was at -5 and now currently it's at -9.

[image]

Can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: I believe spam flags auto cast a downvote. Maybe users are flagging the deleted question somehow, and this circumvents the "you can't vote on deleted or locked posts"?

Comment: Do know that a spam flag also carries an automatic down vote with it. So if more users like you case both a spam flag and a down vote it can collect lots of downvotes in a shot time.

Comment: Side note: at least at some point in the past guidance was to just flag as spam and avoid downvote so *more people can see it* and flag rather than hiding post from main page with a lot of downvotes.

Comment: That question was also detected by Smokey and reported in CharcoalHQ: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/11540?m=53523914  and SOBotics https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/111347?m=48578304 so it got plenty of eyes and opportunity to gather some more votes before it was deleted by the system.

Comment: @yivi yes exactly that what I thought on the first hand that once it gets deleted how come it get more downvotes.

Comment: @rene bots did a good job indeed.